# XML parsing: bs4 lxml not able to parse file. xml changes the header

Tags: xml, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have a file which has the XML declaration like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><EnvelopeProfiles><EnvelopeProfile><businessAlias>SCHNEIDER_TEST</businessAlias>.........
```

When I am using bs4

```
[soupObject = BeautifulSoup(sourceFile,features="xml")]
```

the standalone attribute goes away from the soupObject. Although the tag(say: businessAlias) that I want to access is accessible.

If I use

```
[soupObject = BeautifulSoup(sourceFile,features="lxml")]
```

Then the required tag(say: businessAlias) is not accessible from the soupObject.
What should I do. I want to keep the xml header as it is and access the required attribute.

Comment: @mzjn Updated the XML segment.

Comment: That's not a header and "standalone" is not an attribute. This thing is called the "XML declaration", and its only job is to configure the parser properly before it starts reading the file. It never becomes part of the DOM tree when the file is parsed.